# "Use Of Undeclared Identifier Error"

Tags: swift

I am making a chat app following a tutorial and everything was looking good except for these two errors in the same line. It might have something to do with other ViewControllers or files so just let me know.

Here is the code.

```
import UIKit

class SocketIOManager: NSObject {
static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()

var socket: SocketIOClient = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: "http://192.168.1.197")!)


override init() {
    super.init()
}


func establishConnection() {
    socket.connect()
}


func closeConnection() {
    socket.disconnect()
}


func connectToServerWithNickname(nickname: String, completionHandler: (userList: [[String: AnyObject]]!) -> Void) {
    socket.emit("connectUser", nickname)

    socket.on("userList") { ( dataArray, ack) -> Void in
        completionHandler(userList: dataArray[0] as! [[String: AnyObject]])
    }

    listenForOtherMessages()
}


func exitChatWithNickname(nickname: String, completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    socket.emit("exitUser", nickname)
    completionHandler()
}


func sendMessage(message: String, withNickname nickname: String) {
    socket.emit("chatMessage", nickname, message)
}


func getChatMessage(completionHandler: (messageInfo: [String: AnyObject]) -> Void) {
    socket.on("newChatMessage") { (dataArray, socketAck) -> Void in
        var messageDictionary = [String: AnyObject]()
        messageDictionary["nickname"] = dataArray[0] as! String
        messageDictionary["message"] = dataArray[1] as! String
        messageDictionary["date"] = dataArray[2] as! String

        completionHandler(messageInfo: messageDictionary)
    }
}


private func listenForOtherMessages() {
    socket.on("userConnectUpdate") { (dataArray, socketAck) -> Void in
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("userWasConnectedNotification", object: dataArray[0] as! [String: AnyObject])
    }

    socket.on("userExitUpdate") { (dataArray, socketAck) -> Void in
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("userWasDisconnectedNotification", object: dataArray[0] as! String)
    }

    socket.on("userTypingUpdate") { (dataArray, socketAck) -> Void in
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("userTypingNotification", object: dataArray[0] as? [String: AnyObject])
    }
}


func sendStartTypingMessage(nickname: String) {
    socket.emit("startType", nickname)
}


func sendStopTypingMessage(nickname: String) {
    socket.emit("stopType", nickname)
}
}
```

The line with the errors is,

```
var socket: SocketIOClient = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: "http://192.168.1.197")!)
```

Thanks.

Comment: The *exact* error message would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Yes the error says, "Use of Undeclared Type SocketIOClient" and the second error is "Could Not Infer Type For socket"

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: SocketIOClient is already a source file and it still comes up as an error.

Comment: ??? anybody there. @ZakiAnwarHamdani

Comment: Did you let `SocketIOClient ` private?

Answer (score 1):

Check if Source folder of socket.io-client swift master contains all files or not, if not you can again download that from https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift and copy source folder in your app

Answer (score 0):

Go to the SocketIOClient file, open the File inspector on the right part of Xcode and see if SocketIOClient is part of your app target. The error might be caused by that.

Answer (score 0):

Add `import SocketIO` to fix "Use of Undeclared Type SocketIOClient" error